# Complex csv question: how to generate a final csv after comparing multiple csvs (following manner) using shell scripting?

Tags: shell, awk

```
assume 
file1.csv
Schemaname.tablename.columns
exam1
exam2

filetomatch.csv
exam1
exam2
exam4
exam5
exam6
```

I used

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1) in a' file1.csv filetomatch.csv  >> result.csv (each time one csv is produced)

result
exam 1 
exam 2
```

to match the results.

I have n number of files to comapre to filetomatch.csv

i need out put to be as follows

```
file     matchedcolumns
file1     exam 1
          exam 2
file2     exam 4
.
.
.
filen     exam 2
          exam 3
```

and so on..
How can i concatenate result.csvs everytime with first field as file name.

also is there a way to show the null columns as well
How can i add null values using this?
Example

```
File1 Column1 
File1 Column1 
File2 null 
File3 column3
```

and so on

Comment: This is not clear, could you please be more clear in Logic of getting expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1) in a{ print FILENAME, ($1) }' file1.csv filetomatch.csv`

Comment: Not sure where the column numbers are coming from, based on the original data files there is always one column

Answer (score 0):

`>> result.csv` should be doing the concatenation for you.

for example, create test files

```
$ for i in {1..4}; do echo $i > file$i.txt; done

$ head file?.txt
==> file1.txt <==
1

==> file2.txt <==
2

==> file3.txt <==
3

==> file4.txt <==
4
```

run some awk script on all files, print the filename part of output and concatenate the results

```
$ for f in file{1..4}.txt; do awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' "$f" >> results.csv; done

$ cat results.csv
file1.txt 1
file2.txt 2
file3.txt 3
file4.txt 4
```

Comment: How can i add null values using this?

Example
`File1 Column1
File1 Column 1
File2  null
File3 column3
`

Also is there a way to concat the first field

Example:
`File1 Column1
         Column2
         Column3
File 2 null
File 3 colum1
          column3
File4 null`

Comment: not clear what the format is in the comments, please update the question instead with the additional information.  This answers **"How can i concatenate result.csvs everytime with first field as file name"** but perhaps you meant to ask something else?

Answer (score 0):

found this two useful:

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1) in a{ print FILENAME, ($1) }' file1.csv filetomatch.csv

Merge the commmon values in a column

awk -F, '{ if (f == $1) { for (c=0; c <length($1) ; c++) printf " "; print FS $2 FS $3 } else { print $0 } } { f = $1 }' file.csv